How can I get Directory Utility to work in macOS 15.0.1?
I recently updated to MacOS 15.0.1 and it seems Directory Utility doesn't work for me any longer. How can I fix this?
MacOS 15.0.1

MacOS 10.13.6

EDIT I
Confirm that the path is correct. Here's the "About":

The folder ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.DirectoryUtility.savedState seems to only exist while Directory Utility is running.  When I quit the program it disappears...

Cannot reproduce. I see the tabs Services, Search Policy, and Directory Editor on macOS 15.0.1.

Does it help if you quit the utility, remove ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.DirectoryUtility.savedState and start it again?

The saved app state seems to only exist while the app is open.  It disappears when the app is closed.

Seems your system isn’t behaving correctly (or at least differently that most of our macOS 15 systems). Do you have a good backup?

Can you try with deleting ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.DirectoryUtility.plist? If this doesn't work: what happens if you create a new user account on your Mac and try there, does it work correctly?

I deleted the preference file and emptied the trash but same.  I guess the application is damaged. Will try to reinstall when I have time.

The application is on /System, it can't be damaged. Did you try with a newly created user account.

Is Directory Utility supported or functional?
As part of macOS it is supported.
And it is functional:

Check you are running the 15.0.1 version. Version 6.4 (460.0.1) and it is run from /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Directory Utility.app

Yup, same version.  See picture of About box in the edit.

Hi @Danny you’ll have to ask a different question if you want a different answer. I too have normal Directory Utility on all my macOS 14 and macOS 15 installations.
